# run symfony command as service in ubuntu

Tags: php, linux, symfony, service

i have a command that run normally in terminal :

```
 php -f /home/roshd-user/Symfony/app/console video:convert
```

i want run this command as service in my server. create a vconvertor.conf in /etc/init/ 
.

this service run(start and stop) normally but not execute my command ?!

my command without service is run well and return my result but when use it into a service not execute ?!

**vconvertor.conf contain this codes :**

```
#info
description "Video Convertor PHP Worker"
author      "Netroshd"

# Events
start on startup
stop on shutdown

# Automatically respawn
respawn
respawn limit 20 5

# Run the script!
# Note, in this example, if your PHP script returns
# the string "ERROR", the daemon will stop itself.
script
    [ $( exec php -f /home/roshd-user/Symfony/app/console video:convert
 ) = 'ERROR' ] && ( stop; exit 1; )
end script
```

Comment: The daemonizable command project might help https://github.com/mac-cain13/daemonizable-command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would declare `setuid` and `setgid` in your config as the Apache usergroup ie `www-data`
and make your command run in the `prod` Symfony environment.

```
#info
description "Video Convertor PHP Worker"
author      "Netroshd"

# Events
start on startup
stop on shutdown

# Automatically respawn
respawn
respawn limit 20 5

# Run as the www-data user and group (same as Apache is under in Ubuntu)
setuid www-data
setgid www-data

# Run the script!
exec php /home/roshd-user/Symfony/app/console video:convert -e prod --no-debug -q
```

If you still have issues, it might be worth installing the [`"wrep/daemonizable-command"`](https://github.com/mac-cain13/daemonizable-command) with Composer and making your video convert command extend the `Wrep\Daemonizable\Command\EndlessContainerAwareCommand`. The library also provides [an example of how to use it](https://github.com/mac-cain13/daemonizable-command/tree/master/examples)

Comment: dear Adam thanks. before you answer my question i do same your answer and service is running and execute my command. in my command , execute a ffmpeg command (for convert video) but now my ffmpeg command not execute ?! i  don't now why this happen in the even that running without a service ?!!!!